# Payment from buyer to seller keeping a commission

Tags: paypal, payment

We want to implement a website were we have two types of users:
- Seller (of digital goods)
- Buyer

Is it possible that the buyer pays to the seller and we, the website, retain a commission?
Is it also possible to have a "delay" on the payment to the seller to insure the buyer got what's advertised.

Practical example:

Buyer buys "item x" for 100€
Website gets a commission of 2€ on his PayPal account
Seller get 98€ on his PayPal account automatically after 15 days if no complaint from the buyer is made.

Can anyone point me on the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways you could do this.

1. You could receive the payment into your account.  Then when you are ready to may all of your vendors/merchants, you could use the MassPay API to make the payments to these accounts.  So for example you could set up something, where you may all the merchants either on the 15th, or the 1st of each month, or when ever you wanted to.
2. A second option would be to use Adaptive Payments, and you could use the delayed payment feature with this.  Where you do not actually pay the vendors until after you verified the buyer got what they wanted.  The funds would go into your account, and then you would peform a dealyed payment when you go to pay the vendor.
3. Also both Adaptive Payments and Express Checkout support parallel payments, meaning that you could split up the transaction at the time of the purchase.  However the funds would go into the account right away.  You could use either one of these options if you were not wanting to verify the buyer got what they ordered before paying the vendor.